# Create eclipse P2 update site from folder containing bundles?

Tags: eclipse, p2

Typically an eclipse p2 update site is created inside eclipse through the process of creating a feature project containing one or more plugins/bundles and adding this feature to an eclipse update site project. Finally the update site is build and can be referenced through the update manager in eclipse.

But is it possible to create a p2 update site outside eclipse from a folder only containing a set of already build plugins?

I have looked at:

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_publisher.html

but it assumes that both the bundles AND features are already created.

I have also looked at:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_director_application
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started_for_Releng

but that does not describe how to create a p2 site from a list of bundles.

To simplify my question:

Is it possible to create a full working p2 update site from a local folder containing osgi bundles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Publisher](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher#Features_And_Bundles_Publisher_Application) is the one to generate the p2 repository from bundles.

**Update:**

If you want to let your product showing in p2 UI, you can create p2.inf in your top feature,

```
properties.1.name=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.type.group
properties.1.value=true
```

Of course, you also could add it to a category via [p2 advice file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata).

Comment: @tul, Definitely it's possible. P2's install dialog queries the group IU as the visible IU, so you could create dummy group IU that depends on all your bundles via p2.inf.

Comment: Running FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher followed by CategoryPublisher does the job.